# User Impersonation issue in c#.net

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation

I am writing a c#.net application to execute certain functions under another user context (on the local system). I am using the WinAPI "**LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken)**" for achieving this.

Now the problem that I encounter is, I have a local user in my system who does not have any password. The above LogonUser fails when I give lpszPassword as null or "". All the resources in the internet about "LogonUser" assumes it is taking  a password. So I couldn't get any help. Please help me to figure out a way.

Thank you,

Aron Sajan Philip

Answer (score 0):

Using this WinAPI interface requires that the user have a password.  There are a few examples of software that shows us this, LogMeIn being the most prominent I can think of.

Comment: Is there any other alternative library which allows signing-in without a password?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is done for security purposes.